# How to show travel DIRECTION ARROW in Google Map Javascript API when using POLY LINE?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, routes, polyline

Using Google maps javascript API i want to draw arrow on top of the poly line so when the user is looking at the Map he would understand that some one traveled from here and to here.

**The existing functionality**

[image: img]

**I want something like this**

[image: img]

Please help.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: there is a very good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066387/how-to-add-direction-on-tracking-path-for-google-maps

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 13):

You may calculate the angle between two points, [here's a how-to](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/calculating-the-angle-between-two-points-on-a-circle/).

Depending on the calculated angle you can place a marker at the start-point.
Here you find the description of the markers: http://sites.google.com/site/gmapicons/home/ (Direction indicators)

---

### Edit:

See a demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9gJjj/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9gJjj/)

You'll find a function `fx()` there which expects a  [DirectionsRoute](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRoute) as argument and draws the markers.

---

### Edit2:

Note that you may also use an IconSequence which may be a better approach, See: [Google Map API Direction Triangle Icon Ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267571/google-map-api-direction-triangle-icon-ambiguous/18268601#18268601)

Comment: Hi thanks for this but i am not able to get how to achieve this when i have Geographical coordinates.