# How to add direction on tracking path for google maps

Tags: google-maps, marker

I am showing the tracking on map with marker points and line connecting them.

The problem is that i want to show the direction of travel on the links;

so I am not getting how to show the direction on the line between the marker points.

Is there any way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Showing the direction on the polyline can be accomplished with arrows.

There are some predefined paths that the google maps api3 provides.

See this section of the documentation -
[**SYMBOLS ON POLYLINE**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PredefinedSymbols), that can be used other than an arrow.

Have a look at this fiddle that uses an arrow to indicate the direction on the polyline.

[**DEMO with a sigle symbol**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6eqV/1/)

You can also set the `repeat` property for the symbol so that it repeats for regular intervals.

[**DEMO with repeating symbols**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pc9Rv/)

**JavaScript-**

```
var iconsetngs = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
};
var polylineoptns = {
    path: markers,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
    icons: [{
        icon: iconsetngs,
        offset: '100%'}]
};
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineoptns);
```

The interesting feature of this predefined symbol(*the forward arrow specially*) is that the arrow points towards the exact direction of which your co-ordinates are located. So, that obviously serves the purpose of denoting the direction in a Tracking System.

**UPDATE:** Not sure about the point you are trying to tell in the comments. The markers can be displayed the same way. Here is the code that adds markers with a loop and also set the polyline with arrows:

[**DEMO WITH MARKERS AND POLYLINE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nX8U8/2/)

Javascript:

```
var polylineoptns = {
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        map: map,
        icons: [{
            repeat: '70px', //CHANGE THIS VALUE TO CHANGE THE DISTANCE BETWEEN ARROWS
            icon: iconsetngs,
            offset: '100%'}]
    };
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineoptns);
    var z = 0;
    var path = [];
    path[z] = polyline.getPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) //LOOP TO DISPLAY THE MARKERS
    {
        var pos = markers[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
        });
        path[z].push(marker.getPosition()); //PUSH THE NEWLY CREATED MARKER'S POSITION TO THE PATH ARRAY
    }
```

Comment: How can i get the total distance travelled upto last point.not calculated by start and end point but by the path of travel????

Comment: That's a different question. Consider posting it as a new question.

Comment: JSFiddles updated 2016: [DEMO with a single symbol](https://jsfiddle.net/q6eqV/115/); [DEMO with repeating symbols](https://jsfiddle.net/Pc9Rv/265/); [DEMO WITH MARKERS AND POLYLINE](https://jsfiddle.net/nX8U8/177/).

Comment: Is there any alternatives for OSM?