# Google Map API Direction Triangle Icon Ambiguous

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map API V3 to show the vehicle traveled path and its route directions. But by google direction icon, its very hard to find the directions. The image below explain more
 [image]

and I saw the each icon, it is

[image]
[source](http://tancro.e-central.tv/grandmaster/markers/google-icons/intl-en_ALL-mapfiles.html)

I found the image path, it is 
http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/dir_0.png for [image]

How to make a good directions icons ?

Answer (score 6):

There are some [predefined symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PredefinedSymbols) (e.g. arrows) available in V3 that may be used for an [`IconSequence`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconSequence).
See http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/V3gMT/ for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

P1 AND P2 ARE POINTS.

A point is this:
({ lat:Latitud, lng: Longitud }

Latitud and Longitud are values with coordinates.

```
function MapsP2P(p1, p2)
    //dipuja linea de punto a punto
        { 
            if (p1.lat != 0) { 
                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [
                        new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat, p1.lng),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(p2.lat, p2.lng)
                    ],
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 1,

                    icons: [{
                          icon: {
                                  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                                  strokeColor:'#0000ff',

                                  fillColor:'#000000',
                                  fillOpacity:1
                                },
                          repeat:'100px',
                          path:[]
                       }],

                    map: map
                })
                lines.push(line);
            }
    }
```